# Why does GCC require brackets around new before calling a member function?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a function, which takes an arbitrary number of pointers to a custom class, which are largely instantiated on the spot with new.

Example:

```
addListItems(
    new Item(1, 2, 3),
    NULL);
```

This works. However as soon as I call an init-function on `Item` like this:

```
addListItems(
    new Item(1, 2, 3)->initMoreStuff(4, 5, 6),
    NULL);
```

my compiler throws me the error: `expected ')' before '->' token.
As soon as I do:

```
addListItems(
    (new Item(1, 2, 3))->initMoreStuff(4, 5, 6),
    NULL);
```

it stops complaining. I've tried this very same code with the BCB 6 without any problem, so why exactly is GCC complaining about that?

If I use a maker-function or put the result of 'new' into a variable prior to adding it into the function, it works as well.

And are there any possible side effects of putting the call to `new` into the brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just comes down to parsing. You need the parentheses to indicate that `->` applies to the result of the *new-expression*, rather than to a temporary construction `Item(1, 2, 3)`. This is because [`->` has higher precedence than `new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)
.

Besides such contextual syntax issues, there is absolutely no semantic difference between `new Item(1, 2, 3)` and `(new Item(1, 2, 3))`.

Finally, if "BCB6" accepts your original code then it is buggy (and quite spectacularly so, at that).

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying and for reassuring me. Where in the hierarchy of 'operators' would I find `new` anyway?

Comment: @ATaylor: See the link in my answer; `new` is in level 3.

Comment: Well..I clicked 'submit' the split second before it told me you edited your answer :D

Comment: @ATaylor: Edits? What edits? Lies! Lies I tell thee!  ;)

Comment: And regarding BCB6...it's just being Borland. It's VERY tolerant towards a number of...phenomena. Though I had this one time, where Borland had it right and GCC accepted the faulty solution...can't remember which that was though.

Answer (score 3):

[`->` has higher precedence than `new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), so your original version is parsed as

```
new (Item(1, 2, 3)->initMoreStuff(4, 5, 6))
```

which is syntactically invalid. It looks like BCB 6 got this wrong.

Comment: ...what honestly? Damn, it doesn't list `new` in my list of operator precedence...but of course, that makes perfect sense. It's highly inconvenient, but it makes perfect sense. I need to wait a little before accepting that answer though :D

Comment: @ATaylor There's a good list here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence. I added the link to my answer.

Comment: @ATaylor: You need [a better reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).